# Botan Loading Existing RSA Private Key

Tags: c++, botan

I am using Botan C++ library to sign and verify some license.ini file. I have set up Botan PK_Signer to work with RSA algorithm for encrypting the hash created with PKCS v1.5. This is my code:

```
uint8_t private_key[] = "private key I already have generated."

// Read file content that needs to be signed.
std::string licensePath = argv[1];
std::string fileContents = readFileContent(licensePath);

// Prepare Botan RSA signer. PKCS1 v1.5 is used.
Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG rng;
Botan::secure_vector<uint8_t> secure_key_vector(private_key, private_key + sizeof(private_key) / sizeof(private_key[0]));

/////// NEXT LINE THROWS EXCEPTION!
Botan::RSA_PrivateKey rsa_priv_key(Botan::AlgorithmIdentifier(), secure_key_vector);
//////////////////////////////////////

Botan::PK_Signer signer(rsa_priv_key, rng, "EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5");

// Create signature.
signer.update(cleanStr(fileContents));
std::vector<uint8_t> signature = signer.signature(rng);
std::string hexSignature = Botan::hex_encode(signature);
```

Marked line for generating RSA_PrivateKey object throws an exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF85D2BC3C7 (vcruntime140.dll) in
>   license_signer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x0000021A8FA07000.

I have never before used Botan library. If anyone have any idea why is this happening or idea how to implement this, please assist. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the library and your application are built with the same MSVC runtime options. If they do not match the symptom is typically a crash. Botan build defaults to `/MD`.

Answer (score 2):

> Using Botan 2.12.1

```
#include <string>
#include <botan/auto_rng.h>
#include <botan/auto_rng.h>
#include <botan/base64.h>
#include <botan/pkcs8.h>
#include <botan/rsa.h>
#include <botan/x509_key.h>
#include <botan/data_src.h>
#include <botan/pubkey.h>

//Assuming the private and public keys are in Base64 encoded BER.

Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG rng;
Botan::RSA_PrivateKey keyPair(rng, static_cast<size_t>(4096));
std::string privateKey = Botan::base64_encode(Botan::PKCS8::BER_encode(keyPair));
std::string publicKey = Botan::base64_encode(Botan::X509::BER_encode(keyPair));

//Loading the public key

Botan::SecureVector<uint8_t> keyBytes(Botan::base64_decode(publicKey));
std::unique_ptr<Botan::Public_Key> pbk(Botan::X509::load_key(std::vector(keyBytes.begin(), keyBytes.end())));

//Loading the private key

Botan::SecureVector<uint8_t> keyBytes(Botan::base64_decode(privateKey));
Botan::DataSource_Memory source(keyBytes);
std::unique_ptr<Botan::Private_Key> pvk(Botan::PKCS8::load_key(source));
```

Answer (score 1):

`private_key` data going into the constructor you're trying to use must be DER encoded. Make sure it is. In general, however, you are probably better off using the appropriate `loadKey` method.